# How to target Windows in .NetStandard2.0 project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-standard-2.0

I want to build a .Net Standard 2.0 assembly that copies the Windows version of dependencies into the bin output folder.  Doing so permits and InstallShield build to easily locate the correct assembly for install.

To do this I set the target framework and add CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies.  Specifically, I want the Windows version of System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.dll.  What I get is a version of the assembly that throws the exception "System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Windows Data Protection API (DPAPI) is not supported on this platform."

Manually digging the correct assembly out of the NuGet cache's "runtime" folder and copying it into place allows correct operation.  Please clarify the correct way to get the NuGet runtime for the Windows platform.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Normally, you don't have to care about that. What is your runtime SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to set RuntimeIdentifier in the project.